# Hide div after fading out using jquery, not before

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to fade out a div using jQuery animate and chaining but need to hide the div *after* it fades out, not before. I'm currently using the function:

```
$('#loadhere').hide().stop().animate(
    {
        'opacity' : '0'
    }, 500);
```

I tried putting .hide() after the animate but it still didn't work. I'm sure this is an easy fix but I'm just missing it today.

Comment: You need to put it in the complete callback of the `.animate()` call

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's exactly what [`.fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) does:

```
$('#loadhere').stop().fadeOut(500);
```

Comment: shouldn't be just this '$('#loadhere').fadeOut(500);'

Comment: @MuhammadUmer: That'd probably work as well, but the `.stop()` was in OP's code, so I just left it in.

Comment: Can you advise as to why you'd use fadeOut over animate? I assume because fadeOut also hides the div in the first place?

Comment: @Herp: Because your code was just a long way of writing `.fadeOut`.

Comment: In that case, I've corrected my code and will choose this as the best answer. Thanks, Blender!

Answer (score 2):

Use the complete callback provided by [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

```
$('#loadhere').stop().animate({
    'opacity' : '0'
}, 500, function(){
    $(this).hide()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#loadhere').fadeTo(500, 0, function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling both `.hide()` and `.fadeOut()` in succession *is redundant* -- both set the css property `display:none` when complete.

**[.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)**

> The matched elements will be hidden immediately, with no animation. This is roughly equivalent to calling .css('display', 'none')

**[.fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)**

> The .fadeOut() method animates the opacity of the matched elements. Once the opacity reaches 0, the display style property is set to none, so the element no longer affects the layout of the page.